# Set default accessibility language on iOS to Spanish

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

I'm maintaining an app that was made for english speaking users. I was asked to make a spanish version (they wanted separate apps because of resource size issues). They also want it to be accessible. Now all the labels are set in the app but they are pronounced with an English accent! (sounds horrible :) ) Anyway, I figured out that you can set the accessibilityLanguage to @"es" and that will take care of that. The question then is:

How can I set the default accessibilityLanguage to @"es"? This would override the user's preference. I know Apple doesn't like this but in this case it really does not make sense to have it set to English when all the buttons/labels are spanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This did the trick for me, without having to set `accessibilityLanguage` on each view separately:

```
#import "NSObject+AccessibilityLanguage.h"

@implementation NSObject (AccessibilityLanguage)

- (NSString *)accessibilityLanguage {
    return @"nl";
}

@end
```

Comment: I like this answer. I actually am doing something worse now... I put a method in viewDidLoad of a UIViewController subclass that all my VC's inherit from. This method traverses the view hierarchy recursively and sets all the accessibilityLanguage fields that way. But this is way better! Dank je wel!

Comment: I've found a problem with UITextView. I'm wondering if you ran into the same problem. It seems like UITextView does not respect the language setting. Since I'm pretty much just using the UITextView to display static text I've changed to a UILabel on a UIScrollView.

Comment: accessibilityLanguage only sets "the language in which to speak the accessibility element's label, value, and hint." What about accessibilityTraits? Have you managed to figure this out?